# Script to create heat map in InDesign 5.0 PC?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5, indesign-scripting

I have a table with digits. I want to change the percentage of the fill of each cell to this digit.
Example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for solving your own question, Pylyp! Would you mind posting the answer separate, as an actual answer and accept it? That way we can archive the Q&A properly.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: @Pylyp Upvoted! Now you have 16 rep :)

Comment: I need more, more reps!!! Mu ha ha! Ok, i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanx to [Jarek](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5823064#5823064):

Lets assume a textFrame with your table is selected;

```
var
          mT = app.selection[0].tables[0],
          len = mT.cells.length;

while (len-->0)
          mT.cells[len].fillTint = parseInt(mT.cells[len].contents);
```

Comment: I confess it: I looked at this and thought "what the heck is an `-->` operator?!11one Then I realized it should be parsed as `(len-- > 0)` (i.e. evalulate var len > 0 then decrement)